# Puppeteer scrolling inside modal window

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am working on making a script that allows me to scroll down within a modal window. Currently I can get it so that it scrolls down on the main page of the website - but when I try and select the modal to scroll down I run into issues. I'm assuming it's either something to do with the selector I've used or how I'm going about selecting the window.

```
  await page.goto(
    "https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1562105413977493504/likes",
    {
      waitUntil: "networkidle2",
    }
  );

  await page.waitForTimeout(2000);

  let finishTime = new Date().getTime() + 1 * 60 * 1000;
  const scrollbox = await page.waitForSelector(
    "div.css-1dbjc4n.r-1867qdf.r-1wbh5a2.r-kwpbio.r-rsyp9y.r-1pjcn9w.r-1279nm1.r-htvplk.r-1udh08x"
  );

  await page.focus(scrollbox);
  await autoScroll(page, finishTime);

  async function autoScroll(page, finishTime) {
    await page.evaluate(async (finishTime) => {
      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var totalHeight = 0;
        var distance = 100;
        var timer = setInterval(() => {
          var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
          window.scrollBy(0, distance);
          totalHeight += distance;
          if (
            totalHeight >= scrollHeight ||
            new Date().getTime() > finishTime
          ) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            resolve();
          }
        }, 120);
      });
    }, finishTime);
  }
```

Appreciate any help anyone can offer.